# Why is there no brown color in Java's Color class?

Tags: java

Why is there no built-in brown color in Java's [Color](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html) class? Sure I can make it myself, but it seems like a common enough color that should be available already.

Comment: Seems like this is a question for Oracle to answer?

Comment: Have you ever tried creating a brown color?  It's actually much harder then you think

Comment: Not really hard - new Color(139, 69, 19) should do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short version:  Because the Java team think that extra color constants are not needed.  They clearly said so in 2012!

---

This is one of the few case where there is actually a clearly documented answer<sup>1</sup> to a "Java design" type question.

The following RFE was opened in 2010 against Java 6:

- "additional java.awt.Color constants requested for great justice" :
  https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-6921655

where the requestor proposed adding 10 new constants to assist in developing "chromatically diverse" user interfaces.   He also provided a "helpful" link to a Wikipedia page on [X11 color names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11_color_names).

The RFE was declined with the comment:

> *"We've got along fine without these for about 14 years and I don't
> see a need for them now."*

By extension, requests for (say) "Brown" should get the same response.

---

<sup>1 - I imagine that were also a "slippery slopes" arguments that hypothesizes a never ending stream of RFEs asking for yet more convenience color constants, or Bugs saying that color's X's attributes are wrong / inconsistent with X11 / inconsistent with CSS / "look wrong on my screen", etc.</sup>